Solve $\left| \frac{2x-1}{x+1} \right|=3$

Solve $\left| \dfrac{2x-1}{x+1 }\right|=3$

$\Rightarrow \dfrac{\left| 2x-1 \right|}{\left| x+1 \right|}=3$
$\Rightarrow \left| 2x-1 \right|=3\left| x+1 \right|$
If both $\left| 2x-1 \right|$ and $\left| x+1 \right|$ are positive, then $2x-1=3x+3 \Rightarrow x=-4$
Then I'm stuck. Because if both are negative, then $-(2x-1)=-3(x+1)$ which is the exact same as the positive case. Can one be negative while the other positive? But we are dealing with the sam variable $x$ here so I'm not sure how that's possible. Anyway I'm really confused about the signs here.

For the record, $|2x-1|$ and $|x+1|$ are by definition always positive. I think you meant just $2x-1$ and $x+1$ without the absolute value symbol.

$2$ point divides all $Ox$ on three parts and drawing above appropriate sign for each member of product/division gives clear picture.

Observe the following table
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
                  & (-\infty,-1) & (-1,\frac 12) & (\frac 12,+\infty) \\\hline
 2x-1             & -            & -             & +                  \\\hline
 x+1              & -            & +             & +                  \\\hline
 \frac{2x-1}{x+1} & +            & -             & +
\end{array}
in which we broke down the cases when $2x-1$ and $x+1$ are positive or negative. From the table we can see that $\frac{2x-1}{x+1}>0$ if and only if $x\in(-\infty,-1)\cup(\frac 12,+\infty)$, and $\frac{2x-1}{x+1}<0$ if and only if $x\in(-1,\frac 12)$.
Therefore, we have two cases:
1. $x\in(-\infty,-1)\cup(\frac 12,+\infty)$
In this case, $\left| \frac{2x-1}{x+1} \right| = \frac{2x-1}{x+1},$ so you need to solve equation $\frac{2x-1}{x+1} = 3$ to get $x = -4$. We need to check that the condition from the start holds: $-4\in (-\infty,-1)\cup(\frac 12,+\infty)$ is true, so $x = -4$ is a solution.
2. $x\in(-1,\frac 12)$
In this case, $\left| \frac{2x-1}{x+1} \right| = -\frac{2x-1}{x+1},$ so you need to solve equation $\frac{2x-1}{x+1} = -3$ to get $x = -\frac 25$. We need to check that the condition from the start holds: $-\frac 25\in (-1,\frac 12)$ is true, so $x = -\frac 25$ is one solution.
We exhausted all the cases, so we know that we have exactly two solutions $x = -4,-\frac 25$.

Alternatively, note that $|y| = 3$ if and only if $y^2 = 9$. Substituting $y =  \frac{2x-1}{x+1}$ will lead to quadratic equation $(2x-1)^2 = 9(x+1)^2$, which you can easily solve with quadratic formula.

You are on the right track!
Since both sides are nonnegative for every $x\in\mathbb{R}\backslash\{-1\}$, we can square the proposed equation to get
\begin{align*}
\left|\frac{2x - 1}{x + 1}\right| = 3 & \Longleftrightarrow |2x - 1| = 3|x + 1|\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (2x - 1)^{2} = (3x + 3)^{2}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (2x - 1)^{2} - (3x + 3)^{2} = 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow ((2x - 1) - (3x + 3))((2x - 1) + (3x + 3)) = 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (x + 4)(5x + 2) = 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow x\in\left\{-4,-\frac{2}{5}\right\}
\end{align*}

This is a neat alternative way to solve the problem. +1

If $|y|=a$ and $a\geq 0$ then $y=\pm a$. So in your case $${2x-1\over x+1}=\pm 3$$...

i think you reversed the signs on the $1$s. It should be $2x-1$ and $x+1$

@Almeida  thanks

Yes, it's entirely possible. Suppose $2x-1<0$. Then $2x<1 \iff x <\frac{1}{2}$. This means $2x-1$ is negative as long as this condition holds.
Now we do the same for $x+1$. Suppose $x+1>0$. Then, $x>-1$.
So, as long as $-1 < x < \frac{1}{2}$, we have that $x+1>0$ while $2x-1<0$. Which means in the original equation:
$-(2x-1)=3(x+1) \implies -2x+1=3x+3 \implies 5x=-2 \implies x=-\frac{2}{5}$

Well, your Mobius transformation $  \frac{2x-1}{x+1}$   (without the absolute value signs)   has an easy inverse, just invert the coefficient matrix, so
$$ \frac{x+1}{-x + 2}  $$
For $x=3$  you get $-4$   while for $x=-3$  you get $-2/5$
If you learn some beginning complex analysis,  allowing $z$ to be complex, and taking $ \frac{z+1}{-z + 2}  $   applied to the circle around the origin of radius 3  leads to a circle around $z = -11/5$  of radius $9/5$
There are ways to write this without complex numbers, the outcome was always going to be a circle; you are taking just the intersection with the $x$ axis. See if I can find some posts with that
Later:  start with the distance formula in the plane,
$$ \sqrt{\left(x - \frac{1}{2}\right)^2 + y^2} = \frac{3}{2}  \sqrt{(x+1)^2 + y^2}  $$
square both sides and clear, eventually you have
$$ \left( x + \frac{11}{5} \right)^2 + y^2  = \frac{81}{25}  $$
which is....


Consider the very helpful sub $u=\frac3{x+1}$. Then $$|\tfrac{2x-1}{x+1}|=|u-2|=3.$$
And $u=-1,5\implies x=-4,-\frac25.$
